# C# array with a specific format

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, format

please I need to create a C# array with following exact format:

```
  var sampledata =  {
                      {Day: "Sunday", Quantity: 15},
                      {Day: "Monday", Quantity: 20},
                      {Day: "Tuesday", Quantity: 80}
                    }
```

can we create something like the above in C#. if yes, please how?
thanks...

Comment: It appears that you want to make an array of objects that each have a `Day` and `Quantity` property, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sampledata = new[] {
    new { Day = "Sunday",  Quantity = 15 },
    new { Day = "Monday",  Quantity = 20 },
    new { Day = "Tuesday", Quantity = 80 }
};
```

try a Array or a List of anonymous Types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/bb397696.aspx)

Comment: Some additional explanation rather than just a code snippet would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use object and array together?

```
class Order
{
    public String Day;
    public int    Quantity;
}

Order[] orderArray = new Order[3];
orderArray[0].Date = "Sunday";
orderArray[0].Quantity = 15;
...
```